# Unchecked access ban

Tags: c++

Anyone tried to ban unsafe access operations (like operator* for pointers) from the codebase and replace them with custom functions? The purpose would be to replace UB with an exception and/or to provide more debug information (like file, line or stack-trace) when invalid access happens. For example, custom de-referencing function for pointers could look like this:

```
template<class T> T& value(T* ptr, std::source_location sl = std::source_location::current())
{
    If (ptr) return *ptr;
    throw std::runtime_error(std::format(“bad access in {}:{}:{}”, sl.file_name(), sl.line(), sl.column()));
    // error log could also be printed. It could contain stacktrace.
}
```

Something similar could be implemented for smart pointers, optionals, variants, vector::front etc.
Unchecked access ban could then be enforced by static analyzer like clang TIDY.
Additionally the unsafe() function could be provided for use in some performance critical parts - it would terminate on invalid access in debug build, but wouldn't check validity in release build.

Can anyone see any problem with this scheme? Compilation times? Performance? Verbosity? Or maybe there is a better solution?

EDIT: I will try to clarify few things:

1. I didn’t intend to fix all memory issues here, only unchecked access – nullptr dereference, std::nullopt dereference, some index out of bounds issues etc. (I guess I shouldn’t call it “unsafe access”)
2. My code base has millions of LoC. Rewriting it in a different language is impossible.
3. Checks should be run in release build as well, unless unsafe() function is used instead of value().
4. I prefer expectation to crash because system could recover from exception - It is possible to remove the client that triggered the bug.
5. Even if operating system would crash the app on nullptr dereference the compiler optimizations could rewrite the code, so that some unpredictable behavior would happen instead.
6. std::optional wont crash on nullopt dereference - it will cause hard to predict problems.

Comment: Yes, it's called Java, or C#.

Comment: most compilers add instrumentation to debug builds. More can be added with sanitizers. You cannot portably check if a raw pointer is valid or not. Checking for `nullptr` is false safety that fails in all but the most trivial cases

Comment: How does this `value` function know if `ptr` points to a `T`, or if it is a wild pointer or dangling pointer, and points somewhere in the giggleweeds?

Comment: Every major operating system does this - they guarantee that dereferencing null will crash the program. But the question is, what if the pointer is not null, but still points to something different than you thought it did?

Comment: If this is intended for a new codebase, my better solution would be: Use a different language. Why spend the effort trying to rework C++ into a safer language when you could instead just use an already-existing safer language?

Comment: Are you describing the sanitizers? Since you said you're ok with it only working in debug builds. We have enough tools like this: ASAN, UBSAN, Debug iterators, etc.

Comment: i would just insist on using smart pointer, vector, etc. Then use static analyzer custom rules to verify. Otherwise you will find yourself in a whack-a-mole game spending way to much time on this. Or use c#, its awesome

Comment: How would I access hardware devices without dereferencing a pointer?  We have custom functions that access hardware items, in what we call the Hardware Access Layer (HAL).  The HAL uses a lot of pointers.

Comment: Maybe the trick would be to create variables and tell the linker where they should reside.  I haven't tried this yet.  Pointers are soo much easier.

Comment: On top of all above, unless your code is purely, explicitly  works in a  single-threaded program, none of those measures wouldn't even start to scrape the top of the anthill. ANY access to ANYTHING can be unsafe if it's a resource shared between threads and you will have hard time to ban incorrect use just by banning syntax. There is kind of hat trick of popular languages like Python that they  in reality are single-thread with global locks.

Answer (score 3):

The biggest issue I see with your approach is that it is not that useful. A pointer that equals `nullptr` is the easy bug. The more common and more difficult to track down bugs is other invalid pointers.

For example (poor code, just for the sake of the example it does have a bug!):

```
struct foo { int value = 42; };

struct bar { foo* f; };

int main() {
   bar b;
   {
       foo f; 
       b.f = &f;
   }
   return b.f->value; // UNDEFINED ! Dereferencing a dangling pointer
}
```

`b.f` is a dangling pointer. Smart pointers aside, there is no clean way to set `b.f` to `nullptr` when the object it points to ends its lifetime. It is not possible to know if `b.f` is a valid pointer. The way out is to not get into this situation in the first place by using smart pointers.

You can use a function like your `value` to add debug logs with file, and line number to catch `nullptr` dereferences (and with smart pointers is will also catch most dereference of invalid smart pointers). However, you need to consider that you should not use it always. It adds overhead which is often unwanted. For example with a smart pointer `ptr`:

```
  for (const auto& element : some_container) {
      e(*ptr);
  }
```

You do not want to check in every iteration that the pointer is valid.

Comment: I’m not claiming this solves all memory safety issues. Nullptr dereference bugs are still happening, especially in large codebases(std::optional has checked access as well – it has poor debug info though).
Compiler optimizations could decrease performance overhead. In your example the pointer could be de referenced outside the loop.
Also I’m not sure why using this value() function is Ok for smart pointers, but useless for raw pointers?

Comment: @Yahoo 1) "why using this value() function is Ok for smart pointers, but useless for raw pointers? " I didnt say that. 2) "I’m not claiming this solves all memory safety issues" I am only refering to your question which starts with "Anyone tried to ban unsafe access operation [...] ?". I try to explain why you cannot ban unsafe dereferencing.  3) "n your example the pointer could be de referenced outside the loop." Sure but in real code it is not that obvious. 4) " Nullptr dereference bugs are still happening, ..." sure, as I said, if you want to add debug info for nullptr dereferences the....

Comment: ...then your approach looks ok. Its just not a "ban of unsafe pointer access"

Comment: @Yahoo oh now I see what you mean with "why ... is OK for smart pointers" thats just bad wording in the answer. Will fix it